# How to include other module files while generating a jar in gradle

Tags: java, gradle, jar, dependencies, build.gradle

Lets say I have a spring boot java gradle project with the following structure:

```
project    
│
└───moduleA
│   │   Class1.java
│   │   Class2.java
│   │   build.gradle
│   
└───moduleB
│   │   ClassA.java
│   │   ClassB.java
│   │   build.gradle
│   │
│   build.gradle
```

moduleA has dependency on `moduleB's` classes.
moduleA's gradle file:

```
dependencies {
  implementation project(':moduleB')
}
```

I want to generate jar of `moduleA` which should itself consist of respective classes and dependencies from `moduleB` so that I can expose a single jar of `moduleA`.

But when i check the jar of `moduleA`, it is having the respective files from `moduleB`, but while using the `moduleA` jar and building in other app, it is expecting jar of `moduleB` as well

Following is the jar generation logic i have used:

```
jar {
    from project(':moduleB').sourceSets.main.output


    from {
        configurations.runtimeClasspath.collect { it.isDirectory() ? it : zipTree(it) }
    }
```

I have checked in generated `pom.xml` file, it is expecting `moduleB` jar as dependency.

How can i achieve this without publishing a new jar for `moduleB`?